# Advanced Custom Fields - show on all pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Is there any way of making Advanced Custom Fields(ACF) to set a rule = "ALL"?
So that this specific group shows up on all page types?

Comment: Not specifying any rule will do it.

Answer (score 7):

[Page is not equal to x or is equal to x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvoqv.png)

Just specify that the field should appear on every post other than a particular one or it should appear on that post.

Answer (score 6):

Where it says "Show this field group if" choose "post type", "is equal to" and "page"

Comment: No this will make it only show on a Page post type, not all post types!

Answer (score 4):

Using "post type is equal to post" OR "post type is not equal to post" will work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's where you would use the Rule section and the "and" property and choose every post type you want it enabled for. As far as I know, there is no way to have the custom fields show up on every post type by default.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set it to show if post type is not equal to one of the types inserted by some plugin, which wasn't being used by the editors, for eg. 'Module' or 'Widget block'. Check your list - you'll find something that you don't use.

However, I do like the 'is equal to'+'is not equal to' idea in the other posts more!